# Sampling big dataset

Tags: sampling, dataset, sample-size

I am currently running some models on a very large dataset ([instacart basket analysis](https://www.kaggle.com/c/instacart-market-basket-analysis/data), ~134MM rows) and was wondering on how to pick the right *sample size* to iterate and evaluate different models faster (before training the best model on a way larger chunk of data).

Modeling mainly revolves around evaluating different approaches on recommender systems using [lightfm](https://github.com/lyst/lightfm). I am considering choosing my saple size in the following way:

1. Run baseline model with different sample sizes.
2. Collect accuracy metrics.
3. Check when model accuracy reaches plateau.
4. Pick the corresponding sample size.

Is there anything methodologically wrong with the approach described above?

Comment: With recommender systems the data would be very sparse, so you would usually need largish validation set for trustworthy results.

Comment: That's indeed the case (~50k different products which lead to a very sparse matrix), hence trying to evaluate when sample size stops limiting model performance. I am still doubtful if there's more solid/faster approach to  this.